# how can i delete mp3 item from Recyclerview list and storage

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

my app fetch mp3 files from a folder in the internal storage and i have problème to add a delete method for deleting mp3 items from both recycleview and internal phone storage and i wan to order items from newest to older .
thank you for helping me 
this is my code :

recording class :

```
public class Recording {


String Uri, fileName;
boolean isPlaying = false;


public Recording(String uri, String fileName, boolean isPlaying) {
    Uri = uri;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.isPlaying = isPlaying;
}

public String getUri() {
    return Uri;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return isPlaying;
}

public void setPlaying(boolean playing){
    this.isPlaying = playing;
}
}
```

this the adapter :

```
 package com.recorderlite.audio.audiorecorderlite;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
  import android.os.Build;
  import android.os.Handler;
 import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.transition.TransitionManager;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.SeekBar;
   import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 /**
  * Created by Oualid on 29/10/2017.
  */

  public class RecordingAdapter extends 
  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordingAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Recording> recordingArrayList;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private boolean isPlaying = false;
private int last_index = -1;
private int adapterPosition;
  public Recording recording ;

public RecordingAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Recording> recordingArrayList){
    this.context = context;
    this.recordingArrayList = recordingArrayList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recording_item_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    setUpData(holder,position);

}

private void setUpData(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Recording recording = recordingArrayList.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(recording.getFileName());

    if( recording.isPlaying() ){
        holder.imageViewPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) holder.itemView);
        }
        holder.seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.seekUpdation(holder);
    }else{
        holder.imageViewPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) holder.itemView);
        }
        holder.seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.manageSeekBar(holder);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return recordingArrayList.size();
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
}
public void removeAt(int position) {
    recordingArrayList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, recordingArrayList.size());

    String uri = recording.getUri();
    File file = new File (uri);
    file.delete();
}

public int getAdapterPosition() {
    return adapterPosition;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageViewPlay;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    TextView textViewName;


    private String recordingUri;
    private int lastProgress = 0;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    ViewHolder holder;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Button btn_delete ;
        imageViewPlay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPlay);
        seekBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRecordingname);

        btn_delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

        imageViewPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                Recording recording = recordingArrayList.get(position);

                recordingUri = recording.getUri();

                if( isPlaying ){
                    stopPlaying();
                    if( position == last_index ){
                        recording.setPlaying(false);
                        stopPlaying();
                        notifyItemChanged(position);
                    }else{
                        markAllPaused();
                        recording.setPlaying(true);
                        notifyItemChanged(position);
                        startPlaying(recording,position);
                        last_index = position;
                    }

                }else {
                    if( recording.isPlaying() ){
                        recording.setPlaying(false);
                        stopPlaying();
                        Log.d("isPlayin","True");
                    }else {
                        startPlaying(recording,position);
                        recording.setPlaying(true);
                        seekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
                        Log.d("isPlayin","False");
                    }
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                    last_index = position;
                }

            }

        });
    }
    public void manageSeekBar(ViewHolder holder){
        holder.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if( mPlayer!=null && fromUser ){
                    mPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void markAllPaused() {
        for( int i=0; i < recordingArrayList.size(); i++ ){
            recordingArrayList.get(i).setPlaying(false);
            recordingArrayList.set(i,recordingArrayList.get(i));
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekUpdation(holder);
        }
    };

    private void seekUpdation(ViewHolder holder) {
        this.holder = holder;
        if(mPlayer != null){
            int mCurrentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() ;
            holder.seekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
            holder.seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
            lastProgress = mCurrentPosition;
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        try{
            mPlayer.release();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mPlayer = null;
        isPlaying = false;
    }

    private void startPlaying(final Recording audio, final int position) {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(recordingUri);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("LOG_TAG", "prepare() failed");
        }
        //showing the pause button
        seekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
        isPlaying = true;

        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                audio.setPlaying(false);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        });



    }

}


//this method will remove the item from the list
private void removeHero(final int position) {
    //Creating an alert dialog to confirm the deletion
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to delete this?");

    //if the response is positive in the alert
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            //removing the item
            recordingArrayList.remove(position);

            //reloading the list
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    //if response is negative nothing is being done
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });

    //creating and displaying the alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

this is the recording list activity :

```
package com.recorderlite.audio.audiorecorderlite;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecordingListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private RecyclerView recyclerViewRecordings;
private ArrayList<Recording> recordingArraylist;
private RecordingAdapter recordingAdapter;
private TextView textViewNoRecordings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording_list);

    recordingArraylist = new ArrayList<Recording>();

    initViews();

    fetchRecordings();

}

private void fetchRecordings() {

    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AudioRecorderLite/Audios";
    Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
    File directory = new File(path);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
    if( files!=null ){

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

            Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
            String fileName = files[i].getName();
            String recordingUri = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AudioRecorderLite/Audios/" + fileName;

            Recording recording = new Recording(recordingUri,fileName,false);
            recordingArraylist.add(recording);
        }

        textViewNoRecordings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerViewRecordings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setAdaptertoRecyclerView();

    }else{
        textViewNoRecordings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerViewRecordings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

private void setAdaptertoRecyclerView() {
    recordingAdapter = new RecordingAdapter(this,recordingArraylist);
    recyclerViewRecordings.setAdapter(recordingAdapter);
}

private void initViews() {

    /** setting up the toolbar  **/
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.recording_list);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    /** enabling back button ***/
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    /** setting up recyclerView **/
    recyclerViewRecordings = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewRecordings);
    recyclerViewRecordings.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    recyclerViewRecordings.setHasFixedSize(true);

    textViewNoRecordings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNoRecordings);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}



    public void onClick(View view) {


    }

}
```

Comment: are you getting any crash?

Comment: yes when i click the button the app stoping




public void removeAt(int position) {
    recordingArrayList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, recordingArrayList.size());

    String uri = recording.getUri();
    File file = new File (uri);
    file.delete();
}

Comment: post your log cat error

Comment: 11-25 20:36:58.443 6913-6913/com.recorderlite.audio.audiorecorderlite E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: com.recorderlite.audio.audiorecorderlite, PID: 6913
                                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.recorderlite.audio.audiorecorderlite.Recording.getUri()' on a null object reference

Comment: You posted 435 lines of code. Please, focus on the section of the code that contains the problem, otherwise it will be hard to help you

Comment: at com.recorderlite.audio.audiorecorderlite.RecordingAdapter.removeAt(RecordingAdapter.java:95)
                                                                                              at com.recorderlite.audio.audiorecorderlite.RecordingAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(RecordingAdapter.java:127)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
                                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)

Comment: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)

Comment: can you give me another way to get the path of the item

Comment: Please `edit` down to an  **[Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change below code

```
public void removeAt(int position) {
    recordingArrayList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, recordingArrayList.size());

    String uri = recordingArrayList.get(position).getUri();
    File file = new File (uri);
    file.delete();
}
```

> String uri = recording.getUri();

This line cause the problem as you get a uri from a null object so change it to

```
String uri = recordingArrayList.get(position).getUri();
```

Comment: @OualidOukassou happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this and it works perfectly.
You must need the the filename that you want to delete from the directory you are creating. To call the function use `deleteItem(getAdaptorPosition());`

```
private void deleteItem(int index) {

           recordingArrayList.remove(index);
           notifyItemRemoved(index);
           notifyItemRangeChanged(index, recordingArrayList.size());

           File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
           String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AudioRecorderLite/Audios/";
           Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
           File directory = new File(path);
           File[] files = directory.listFiles();
           Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
           String fileName = files[index].getName();
           String recordingUri = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AudioRecorderLite/Audios/" + fileName;
           File myfile = new File(recordingUri);
           myfile.delete();
       }
```